# How can I add color between \/ in terminal?

Tags: bash, ascii, ascii-art

I am making text ASCII art for my `.profile` in terminal, and trying to colorize it. At first I as going to use the `cat` command and `heredoc` for printing out my art, but then I couldn't get the colors inside of the heredoc to work. So I went with the dirty fix, I am using `echo -e` for each line and then coloring it. If there's a better way, please let me know! Right now, I am having this problem.

Full picture:

```
    _            _
 __| |_ __  __ _| |__
/ _` | '  \/ _` | / /
\__,_|_|_|_\__,_|_\_\
```

Part that I am coloring:

```
/ _` | '  \/ _` | / /
```

Coloring:

```
echo -e "\033[37m/ _\` |\033[36m '  \\\033[1;35m/ _\` | / /";
```

Outputs:

```
/ _` | '  \033[1;35m/ _` | / /
```

As you can see, I am trying to insert a new color in between the `\/`. The `\` is treating the `\033[1;35m` literally. Is there a way to color the change the color between the `\/` without altering the image?

Also, I am using Mac OSX Lion.

Comment: Try with 5 bars instead of 3 `\\\\\033[1;35m/`

Comment: Worked. `\\` for a slash? `\\` for another slash? `\033` for an escape. Why did I need 2 slashes though? Also, post it as an answer :)

Comment: please change the title of your question.. this title is just a little better than "PLease answer my question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with 5 bars instead of 3 `\\\\\033[1;35m/`

As for why, bash escape `\\\\` to `\\` then echo -e, escape it again to `\`. If you enable set -x (trace mode) you will see the command executed after bash processing (set +x to disable it).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a `heredoc` you may use the `$'string'` feature of Bash which makes it possible to directly use ANSI C escape sequences for colouring output.

```
man bash | less -p "\\$'string'"

(
asciiart=$'
    _            _
 __| |_ __  __ _| |__
\033[37m/ _` |\033[36m \'  \\\033[1;35m/ _` | / /\033[m
\\__,_|_|_|_\\__,_|_\\_\\
'
echo "$asciiart" | sed '1d;$d'
)
```

To increase readability you may want to try figlet.

http://rudix.org/packages-def.html#figlet

Answer (score 0):

What about simply using a few lines of POSIX printf

```
printf "\e[37m/ _\` |\e[36m \....\n"
```

instead of messing with all the pesky escape problems?